# Normal subgroup of index m contains every element of order n where m and n are relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ of index $m$. If $n$ is a positive integer such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$, show that all the elements of order $n$ are in $K$.

I could solve this if $G$ is finite as follows:
Let $g$ be an element of order $n$.
$|gK|$ divides $|G|$ using canonical epimorphism, again $|gK|$ divides $|G/K|$. Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, we get order of $gK$ is $1$.

What if $G$ is infinite?

Comment: Every element of order $n$ is an $m$-th power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument doesn't actually require $G$ to have finite order. Indeed, if $g$ has order $n$ and $\pi:G\to G/K$ is the canonical map, it follows from
$$ \pi(g)^n=\pi(g^n)=\pi(e)=e$$
that the order of $\pi(g)$ divides $n$. Now proceed as in your question.